# Can you please suggest books related to this theory of integration?

Tags: integration, reference-request, vector-analysis, physics, book-recommendation

[image]

**Reference:-Introduction to Electrodynamics-David J. Griffith** [image]

**My Question**

I have come across [surface integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral) and [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) over a vector field. usually, the integrand is a scalar function, after dot product. What about the equation (2.5). Can you suggest some textbook of Mathematics for this kind of integral? Here integrand is purely vector field. In lower class, I integrated just component-wise. I really want to know, How is it working? Please help me.

Comment: It *is* just component-wise integration...

Comment: @HansLundmark Why do we do like that?

Comment: Ususally by definition, if you define vectors as tuples of real numbers. Or else, if you like to think of geometrical vectors instead, you can define the integral as the limit of Riemann sums, and note that sums and limits of vectors are done component-wise when you introduce coordinates with respect to some basis.

Comment: ok. Thank you@HansLundmark

Comment: @HansLundmark I have one more doubt raised in my mind. What would be the geometrical interpretation of the integration? We know, a single variable definite integral is the area under the curve. Here, How can I interpret geometrically? What is the procedure for editing the question by including new question? Please help me.

Comment: I think one should downplay the “area under the curve” interpretation and just think of integrals as “summing infinitely many infinitesimally small terms”. This intuition works for ordinary integrals $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$, and it works for integrals like those in your question. Regarding changing the question by editing, it's usually better to ask a new question instead (otherwise previous discussions and answers might become confusing to someone reading the question in the future).

Answer (score 2):

You should read "Div, Grad, Curl, and All That"

[https://www.amazon.com/Div-Grad-Curl-All-That/dp/0393925161](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393925161)

It is an exceptional text to pair with any vector calculus text. My personal favorite is

[https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-III-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387909850/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1518622074&sr=1-1&keywords=marsden+calculus+3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387909850)

which is very thorough, and very inexpensive if purchases used.

Comment: Div grad curl is an exceptionally clear book on the subject.